# combobox value in c sharp

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

How can have a combobox which has all values from a specific column in database. I have a column named `StudentName` and I want to have a combobox that has all values of `StudentName` in it.

```
sql = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=PC-PC\PC;Initial Catalog=Anbar;Integrated Security=True");
adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from School", sql);
```

How should I continue? Please give some codes for continuing these codes any help will be appreciated.

Comment: i can do it just with a row ID.

Comment: datatable.rows[rowid][columnname].tostring(); it just show me only one value not all students names

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sqlCon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=PC-PC\PC;Initial Catalog=Anbar;Integrated Security=True");
  SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select StudentName from School", sqlCon);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        yourComboBox.DataSource = dt;
        yourComboBox.DisplayMember = "StudentName";
        yourComboBox.ValueMember = "StudentName";
```

Also read this [Populate Date from Database in a ComboBox](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8009/Populate-data-from-database-in-a-ComboBox)

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select StudentName from School", sqlCon);
DataTable dat = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dat);
cmb.DataSource = dat;
cmb.DisplayMember = "StudentName";
cmb.ValueMember = "StudentName";
```